# How can we sample from a list of strings based on their probability of occurrence in the list in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a `List[(String, Double)]` variable where the second element of tuple denotes the probability of the string  in first element appearing in a corpus. An example would be `[(Apple, 0.2), (Banana, 0.3), (Lemon, 0.5)]` where an Apple appears with a probability of 0.2 in the list of strings. I want to randomly sample from the list of strings based on their probability of appearance something along the lines of numpy `random.choice()` method. What would be the correct way to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution:

```
def choice(samples: Seq[(String, Double)], n: Int): Seq[String] = {
  val (strings, probs) = samples.unzip
  val cumprobs = probs.scanLeft(0.0){ _ + _ }.init
  def p2s(p: Double): String = strings(cumprobs.lastIndexWhere(_ <= p))
  Seq.fill(n)(math.random).map(p2s)
}
```

An usage (and verify):

```
>> val ss = choice(Seq(("Apple", 0.2), ("Banana", 0.3), ("Lemon", 0.5)), 10000)
>> ss.groupBy(identity).map{ case(k, v) => (k, v.size)}
    Map[String, Int] = Map(Banana -> 3013, Lemon -> 4971, Apple -> 2016)
```

Comment: Great, concise implementation! Please consider a proposal: current complexity is `n*m`, using `SortedMap` and `maxBefore()` could reduce it to `n*log(m)`.

Answer (score 1):

A very naive *(and inefficient)* solution would be to create a List of 100 elements that repeats each of the original elements the amount of times needed to respect its probabilities. Then you can randomly shuffle that List and finally take the first element.

```
import scala.util.Random

final val percent_100 = BigDecimal(100)

def choice[T](data: List[(T, Double)]): T = {
  val distribution = data.flatMap {
    case (elem, probability) =>
      val scaledProbability = BigDecimal(probability).setScale(
        scale = 2,
        BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN
      )

      val n = (scaledProbability * percent_100).toIntExact

      List.fill(n)(elem)
  }

  Random.shuffle(distribution).head
}
```

However, I am sure there should be better ways of solving this.